Can I create an isosceles triangle 2d curve that I can move points and sweep it on an arc?
I need an isosceles triangle 2d curve that I can move points and sweep it on an arc.
Can a 2d curve be made in this shape?

That’s way too little detail, but yes, of course it can be that shape. What do you mean by “move points and sweep an arc,” though? Curve points are not expected to be animated, and if it’s just a triangle why not use a mesh instead?

Maybe draw an image and post it showing what you mean by " isosceles triangle 2d curve that I can move points and sweep it on an arc"  showing directional arrows of it sweeping in the direction you mean.

I love this social media colon restoration after peristalsis. The right to comment without knowing the product fully. There is enough detail for anyone who has seen this problem using a curve to mesh sweep node. So I get a downgrade. The answer that I found is one must create meshes first then position them into a boolean node by transform.

Do you want to create the triangle "inside" the GN modifier attached to the curve (the arc ?), or do you have the triangle created in Edit Mode and it is an input to the GN modifier ? In the first case, how are you "moving" the vertices of the triangle ?

Blender does not do parametrics, as in create two geonode 2d shapes then boolean them then sweep them on a path. Instead Blender builds the 3d shapes then you can boolean resulting in a huge amount of vectors getting deleted after getting created. So booleaning a 3d model is very cpu/gpu consumptive in animations for each rendered frame. If I am spouting ignorance please correct me. I have done many tests on this and fallen prey to being told I am doing it wrong.

Blender is not wrong and parametrics has a place for better performance.

Here's a couple of nodes to get you started.  I'm not that mathematically inclined so I didn't understand the arc portion of your question.



The arc portion is the curve input on the curve to mesh.

(Using Blender 4.2.3)

This GeometryNodes modifier is attached to the curve along which "an isosceles triangle 2d curve" is swept. Dark pink nodes are modifying the vertices of a Curve Circle to make it isosceles, based on its Height and Half-base provided as user-defined inputs.
(Blender 4.2.3+)

This adds to Rick T's answer, which I upvoted.
The triangle would be swept with an arc, as below, but you also need the shade auto smooth modifier.
Handily, it is also a node group.


